# Can't seem to override Checkout Controller in Magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to make some changes to the Checkout controller in my Magento store, however, when I try to put the controller file into my local directory it does not seem to be respecting the local file for this.

I have checked that the files are in the same spot in their respective code pools and the files are named the same thing, it just will not do it.

- /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers|CartController.php
- /app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/controllers|CartController.php

Those are the file paths for the two files I have.

Is there something special about the checkout files in Magento that prevent them from being overridden?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

FYI, controller overriding doesn't work just by placing the related file in local folder with the same folder structure. Rather you need to follow the following syntax for the purpose:

```
<config>
    <frontend> [1]
        <routers>
            <checkout> [2]
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <yourModule before="Mage_Checkout">Namespace_Module_Overwrite_Checkout</yourModule> [3]
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

```
[1] Depending on the controllers area ,"frontend" or "admin"
[2] Router node of the module to be overridden (look it up in the config.xml of that module)
[3] The tag  can be anything, it must be unique within the  node.
Your_Module_Overwrite_Checkout (is mapped to directory)
Your/Module/controllers/Overwrite/Checkout/

Hope this helps.
Regards
MagePsycho
```

Comment: This is a curious design decision for the Magento team as everything else inside a module can be easily overridden by putting it in the right spot in the local code pool.

Answer (score 1):

Read the Magento Wiki by lichal for a working and complete solution:
https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/How+To+Overload+a+Controller