# Magento: Overriding customer account controller

Tags: magento

Hi I'm trying to override Mage_Customer_AccountController, so that I can extend the createPostAction method. For the life of me I can't seem to do this, it either throws a 404 page, which suggests that its not the right path for the file or it defaults to orignal.

```
<rewrite>
       <company_modulename_account>
           <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/account/#]]></from>
           <to>/modulename/account</to>
       </company_modulename_account>
</rewrite>
```

My controller is located here local/company/modulename/controllers/AccountController.php

Comment: do you absolutely have to override it? It is much much better practice to use an Event Observer that listens for the customer_save_after event and performs your required steps in a decoupled, upgrade-safe manner

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Instead, you can try as:

```
...   
 <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <company_modulename before="Mage_Customer">Company_Modulename</company_modulename>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
...
```

And create a controller class: 
app/code/[codePool]/Company/Modulename/controllers/AccountController.php
 with the following code:

```
require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';
class Company_Modulename_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
    public function createPostAction(){
        die('Overriden');
    } 
}
```

Here is more info about controller overriding:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7117076/887385

Good Luck!!

Comment: With Magento 1.7 only this works for me:
<company_modulename before="Mage_Customer_AccountController">Company_Modulename</company_modulename>

Comment: @KevinHorst +1 for the comment. Am on 1.6.X C.E. investigating whats the issue and will update this one.

Comment: Works fine with `before="Mage_Customer"` on magento 1.9