# how to Override the Core module in Magento 1.6.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I created a module as like customer in mage and i want to Use before my Mage module I followed the steps shown in here 
 [Magento: Overriding customer account controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350044/magento-overriding-customer-account-controller)

but its not working for me.. I am magento 1.6.2.0.

Is version will be any problem for this..?

```
  <frontend>
<routers>
<customer>
<args>
<modules>
<Gmodule_Customer before="Mage_Customer">Gmodule_Customer</Gmodule_Customer>
</modules>
</args>
</customer>
</routers>
</frontend>
```

Comment: have you activated the module in `etc/modules`?

Comment: ya i activated and it's showed in enabled mode in my admin page also..