# Magento: Login customer by email and locate to customer account

Tags: magento, authentication

in our old shop system we send the customer login links, so that they do not need to remember there password. How can we login a customer by email only via the magento functions and locate hom to the customer account after?

Is this possible with magento?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but  you would have to create your own custom module.

Take a look @

> loginPostAction() in app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
>
> login() in app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php

In your custom module, you could create a controller that extend/override your customer controller (see [Magento: Overriding customer account controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350044/magento-overriding-customer-account-controller))

```
require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';
class MagePal_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
    public function loginByEmailPostAction(){
        
      /** @var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer */
      $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                    ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
                    ->loadByEmail('example@example.com');

      if ($customer->getId()) {
        $this->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
        $this->renewSession();
        return true;
      }
    } 
}
```

Please note that this may cause additional security risks.