# Php Magento - How to redirect user to a custom store after login

Tags: magento-1.8

I want to redirect a user after sign in to a store after checking customer group type. Now in **login.phtml** file, where should i make change? Where should i apply my condition of checking of customer type in the code? please help.

Answer (score 0):

After successful sign in login.phtml file will not be executed.

So you need to override this controller class

Mage_Customer_AccountController

if you don't know how to override controller then refer this link

[Magento: Overriding customer account controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350044/magento-overriding-customer-account-controller)

After that write your code like this in your new AccountController class

```
 public function _loginPostRedirect(){
     $session = $this->_getSession();
     Mage::log($session->getCustomerGroupId()); }
```

once log in from frontend and check your log /var/log/system.log you will find customer  group id

Comment: `Mage_Customer_AccountController` is a class name not a function