# Magento: There should be minimum 10 total quantity of cart for wholesale customer group to checkout

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I have created a customer group Wholesale and if this grouped customer is logged in he'd see different prices. Anyway, I want to restrict this group, they must purchase minimum 10 quantity of any product, say 4items of product A and 6 items of product B in order to proceed to the checkout. I tried changing minimum quantity in inventory management but it applies on each product individually.
I want it to act as a whole, i.e total quantity in cart.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the CHECKOUT button and display a message instead by checking following two conditions in phtml page(s).

```
10 <= Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount()
YOUR_GROUP_ID = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId()
```

To prevent "checkout/onepage" manually from url

1. Turn on "Template Path Hints" and find phtml file.
2. Open the phtml file and put this on top to find where the controller is.
   `<p><?php print_r($this->getRequest()->getModuleName()); ?></p>`
   `<p><?php print_r($this->getRequest()->getControllerName()); ?></p>`
   `<p><?php print_r($this->getRequest()->getActionName()); ?></p>`
3. Find it and go to the Action method. Break the code or do return call to make sure you are in the right place.
4. If this is a core controller file the better way is to override the controller. [Click here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110042/cant-seem-to-override-checkout-controller-in-magento). You can find more online. If you could not get to override the controller only option you have is editing on the same page.

Comment: Hiding checkout isnt the only thing because when we try "checkout/onepage" manually from url, the checkout process starts.

Comment: Why don't you add the same if condition to checkout controller.

Comment: Well I'm afraid I do not know how to achieve this. Kindly help me on this. Help will be highly appreciable
p.s im new to magento

Comment: I will edit my post. It is not clear writing here in comment.

Answer (score 0):

```html
SET MINIMUM ORDER Quantity FOR WHOLESALE CUSTOMER GROUP This is the tricky bit.

Open your app/design/frontend/default/[your theme]/template/checkout/cart.phtml

1. Add the following code to the beginning of the file, right above <div class="cart">

<?php $logged_in = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' )->isLoggedIn();

if ($logged_in) { $group = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(); $totalItems = Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getItemsQty();

$minimum_qty = 10; } ?>

This code checks if the user is logged in, and if so, finds out which Customer Group they are in, their cart qty, and creates a variable to store what you want the minimum order qty to be.

2. Find the following code on your page (it will appear twice):

<ul class="checkout-types"> <?php foreach ($this->getMethods('top_methods') as $method): ?> <?php if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method)): ?> <li><?php echo $methodHtml; ?></li> <?php endif; ?> <?php endforeach; ?> </ul>

This is the code that renders the checkout buttons.

Replace the first instance of that code with:

<?php if (($group == 2 && $totalItems > $minimum_qty) || $group != 2): ?> <ul class="checkout-types"> <?php foreach ($this->getMethods('top_methods') as $method): ?> <?php if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method)): ?> <li><?php echo $methodHtml; ?></li> <?php endif; ?> <?php endforeach; ?> </ul> <?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($group == 2 && $totalItems < $minimum_qty): ?> <span style="color: red">Note: The minimum qty  for Wholesale customers is 10. Please add more items to your cart.</span><br /><br /> <?php endif; ?>

and the second instance with:

<?php if (($group == 2 && $totalItems > $minimum_qty) || $group != 2): ?> <ul class="checkout-types"> <?php foreach ($this->getMethods('top_methods') as $method): ?> <?php if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method)): ?> <li><?php echo $methodHtml; ?></li> <?php endif; ?> <?php endforeach; ?> </ul> <?php endif; ?>

What this does is prevent the checkout buttons from rendering if the customer is a wholesale customer ($group == 2) and their cart qty is less than the minimum you want ($totalItems > $minimum_qty). An error message will be displayed in red at the top of the cart page.

The buttons will render for everyone else, with no error message.
```

Comment: Dear, This code works only on "checkout/cart/" page. When we go to "checkout/onepage" the checkout process starts.

Comment: you can make code for onepage. for place order button as we have done for cart page.